# I am unable to catch the data coming from paytm payment gateway after payment in mvc?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, paytm

I am setting Payment Gateway for payment in my `.NET MVC` website. On my local environment everything is working fine but when I deployed it on server the `Request.Form.Keys` count became zero.

I made a simple method and print the data coming from paytm after transaction it is showing all data when I run it on my local but when deployed on server it giving 0 count of form data. I am unable to get the solution of my problem: why is it happening on server and working on local? I try to count `Request.Form.Keys` but it is showing 0 count but on local the response is as I want.

```
public ActionResult PaymentTryl(int number)
{
    var ORDERID = Utility.RandomString(10);
    //req.UID = 20;
    //var orderid = PaytmPaymentRequest(req);
    Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    parameters.Add("MID", WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Paytm_MID"].ToString());
    parameters.Add("CHANNEL_ID", WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Paytm_CHANNEL_ID"].ToString());
    parameters.Add("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Paytm_INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"].ToString());
    parameters.Add("WEBSITE", WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Paytm_WEBSITE"].ToString());
    parameters.Add("EMAIL", "Cool17@gmail.com");
    parameters.Add("MOBILE_NO", "9993160027");
    parameters.Add("CUST_ID", "20");
    parameters.Add("ORDER_ID", ORDERID);
    parameters.Add("TXN_AMOUNT", number.ToString());
    parameters.Add("CALLBACK_URL", WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebSiteURL"].ToString() + "/Testing/paymentTestallbackurl"); //This parameter is not mandatory. Use this to pass the callback url dynamically.

    try
    {
        string paytmChecksum = CheckSum.generateCheckSum(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Paytm_MERCHENTKEY"].ToString(), parameters);
        string outputHTML = "<html>";
        outputHTML += "<head>";
        outputHTML += "<title>Merchant Checkout Page</title>";
        outputHTML += "</head>";
        outputHTML += "<body>";
        outputHTML += "<center><h1>Please do not refresh this page...</h1></center>";
        outputHTML += "<form method='post' action='" + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Paytm_transactionURL"].ToString() + "' name='f1'>";
        foreach (string key in parameters.Keys)
        {
            outputHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='" + key + "' value='" + parameters[key] + "'>";
        }
        outputHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='CHECKSUMHASH' value='" + paytmChecksum + "'>";
        outputHTML += "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        outputHTML += "document.f1.submit();";
        outputHTML += "</script>";
        outputHTML += "</form>";
        outputHTML += "</body>";
        outputHTML += "</html>";
        //Response.Write(outputHTML);
        ViewBag.paymentHtml = outputHTML;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Utility.ExceptionLogging.SendErrorToText(ex);
    }
    return View();
}

[AllowCrossSite]
public ActionResult paymentTestallbackurl()
{
    try
    {
        bool VALID_CHECKSUM;
        Dictionary<String, String> paytmParams = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        string paytmChecksum = "";
        //Request.Form.Keys.Count

        foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
        {
            paytmParams.Add(key.Trim(), Request.Form[key].Trim());

            //if (key.Equals("CHECKSUMHASH"))
            //{
            //    paytmChecksum = Request.Form[key];
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    paytmParams.Add(key.Trim(), Request.Form[key].Trim());
            //}
        }
        //bool isValidChecksum = CheckSum.verifyCheckSum(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Paytm_MERCHENTKEY"].ToString(), paytmParams, paytmChecksum);

        ViewBag.MyDictionary = paytmParams;
        return View(paytmParams);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionLogging.SendErrorToText(ex);
        throw;
    }
    return View(Request);
}
```

Count of the request data must be greater than zero.

Comment: Do you have different configuration values on your server than local? Are any of the configuration values specific to local and need updating to work for the server/callbacks? Do you have a license that will only work on your local machine that needs to be active for the server to function correctly?

Comment: There is no configuration Special configure for localhost and server .

Comment: So which is it, no configuration or "special" configuration...? Your issue is likely with the configuration, but since you have not provided any of it for either environment, you will need to review them yourself and determine the issue.